# iOS Bad URL for NSUrlConnection

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection, nsurl, nsurlrequest

I have a url in an NSString called myUrl.  When I NSLog myUrl I see the following:

```
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57665723%2FChocolatesRUs%2FJellies%2FUn-sugared%2Fgen%20no%20sugar.pdf
```

I then try connecting using this url as follows:

```
NSURL* url = [ NSURL URLWithString:nextFileURL ];
NSMutableURLRequest* request =  [ [ NSMutableURLRequest alloc ] initWithURL: url ];
NSURLConnection* conn = [ [ NSURLConnection alloc ] initWithRequest: request delegate: self ];
```

I am getting the following error:

```
errorcode=-1000, error=Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0x27e540 {NSUnderlyingError=0x26d800 "bad URL", NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL}
```

I have tried using

```
NSString* myUrl = [myUrl stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

but this doesn't work either.

Can anyone see the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can escape your url with `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` instead of `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`.

Answer (score 1):

stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding is remove spaces and adding percents

```
NSString *urlString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&street=%@&street2=&city=%@&state=%@&
zipcode=%@&candidates=10", address.address2,address.city, address.state, address.zip5];
NSLog(@"BAD URL - %@",urlString ); // there is space in url

NSString *encodedUrl = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@" CORRECT URL - %@", encodedUrl); // url encode that space by %20


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL RLWithString:encodedUrl]];
```